# cells.InnerHtml not getting correct way

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void ReadHtmlTable(string patientName, string startHour, string startMinute, int rowspan)
            {
                 for(int i = 0; i <= tableAppointment.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j <= tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells.Count - 1; j++)
                        {
                            if(tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j].InnerHtml.Trim() == startHour)
                            {
                                if(tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j + 1].InnerHtml.Trim()== startMinute)
                                {
                                    tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j + 2].InnerText = patientName;
                                    tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j + 2].RowSpan = rowspan;
                                    tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j + 2].Style.Add("color", "green");
                                    tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j + 2].Style.Add("background", "green");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }
```

Above code is my server side code which executes on OnSaveStateComplete(EventArgs e) event . i am reading my html table in c#. when i check its first cell second cell text then its give result like this "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t08:00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" .I have use trim at end but not work.

Comment: Replace InnerHtml.Trim() with InnerText.Trim(). I suppose you have something like "<br>" instead of "\r\n" there.

Comment: <td width="70px">
         08:00
        </td>

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
string str = "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t08:00\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t".Trim('\t', '\r', '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to RegEx it out of there with
`RegEx.Replace(tableAppointment.Rows[i].Cells[j + 1].InnerHtml, "\\s+", "");`

The Regex.Replace method at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx).  The example there also has dealing with white space.

Comment: Have you traced to see what the insert and results are pre and post the replace or trim functions recommended? Do you have control over the HTML table, it would probably be better to just not input so many tabs etc. inside the cell itself.  More information, I'm sure we can get it worked out with you.

We've all been assuming the \r \t etc. are newline information - is the string actually being returned with the escape sequences such that "\\r\\n\\t" etc. or escape sequences.  As that would require a different approach (in this case pattern).

Comment: @John I did not down vote your question, you might want to check your information.  Perhaps though you need to include some more information and we can help.